# import langchain.indexes not Found in python

Tags: python

I am trying to use langchain VectorstoreIndexCreator, But its continuously giving this error.
I have installed langchain and chromadb .
Tried different ide's pyhcarm , intellij, Visual studio but this error is still there .
Any idea what i am missing
I am using python: 3.7.3 and latest langchain version

[image]

Comment: Make sure there's no file named `langchain.py` in your working directory.